# Pandas: back unique values to column in order

Tags: python, pandas, unique

I'm not sure how I should proceed in this case.

Consider a df like bellow and when I do `df.A.unique()` -> give me an array like this `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

But also I want the index of this values, like `numpy.unique()`

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4], 'B':[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]})
df.A.unique()
>>> array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

And

```py
np.unique([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4], return_inverse=True)
>>> (array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]))
```

How can I do it in Pandas? Unique values with index.

Comment: what you mean index here

Comment: @WeNYoBen He wants the index of the first encountered unique value

Comment: `np.unique(df.A.values,return_inverse=True)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use a dict to [`.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with index of `.unique()`:

```
df.A.map({i:e for e,i in enumerate(df.A.unique())})
```

---

```
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    2
7    2
8    3
```

Answer (score 4):

In `pandas` we have `drop_duplicates`

```
df.A.drop_duplicates()
Out[22]: 
0    1
3    2
6    3
8    4
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

To match the `np.unique` output `factorize`

```
pd.factorize(df.A)
Out[21]: (array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]), Int64Index([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64'))
```

Comment: `factorize` is a good option here for this usecase.you can directly use it on series too bdw :) `df.A.factorize()`